# python 3.x joblib simple save function

Tags: python, pickle, joblib

I'm trying to create a simple joblib function, which will evaluate the expression and pickle the result, while checking for the existence of the pickle file.
But when I put this function in some other file and import the function after adding the path of the file to sys.path. I get errors.

```
from pathlib import Path
import joblib as jl    
def saveobj(filename, expression_obj,ignore_file = False):
    fname = Path(filename)
    if fname.exists() and not ignore_file:
        obj = jl.load(filename)
    else:
        obj = eval(expression_obj)
        jl.dump(obj,fname,compress = True)        
    return obj
```

Sample call:

```
rf_clf = saveobj(file, "rnd_cv.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))", ignore_file=True)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-02c2cae43c5d> in <module>
      1 file = Path("rf.pickle")
----> 2 rf_clf = saveobj(file, "rnd_cv.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))", ignore_file=True)

~/Dropbox/myfnlib/util_funs.py in saveobj(filename, expression_obj, ignore_file)
     37         obj = jl.load(filename)
     38     else:
---> 39         obj = eval(expression_obj)
     40         jl.dump(obj,fname,compress = True)
     41     return obj

~/Dropbox/myfnlib/util_funs.py in <module>

NameError: name 'rnd_cv' is not defined
```

I guess, python needs to evaluate the function locally, but since the objects don't exist in that scope, it is throwing this error.
Is there a better way of doing this. I need to do this repeatedly, that's why a function.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the documentation of `eval`:

> Help on built-in function eval in module builtins:
>
> eval(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
>
> ```
> Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.
>
> The source may be a string representing a Python expression
> or a code object as returned by compile().
> The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
> defaulting to the current globals and locals.
> If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
> ```

It has arguments for global and local variables. So, in your case, you can:

```
from pathlib import Path
import joblib as jl    
def saveobj(filename, expression_obj,global,local,ignore_file = False):
    fname = Path(filename)
    if fname.exists() and not ignore_file:
        obj = jl.load(filename)
    else:
        obj = eval(expression_obj, global, local)
        jl.dump(obj,fname,compress = True)        
    return obj
```

The code can be changed to:

```
rf_clf = saveobj(file, "rnd_cv.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))", globals(), locals(), ignore_file=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post answer my own question, when I saw @youkaichao answer. Thanks a lot.
One more way to skin the cat: (although limited to keyword arguments)

```
def saveobj(filename,func, ignore_file = False, **kwargs):
    fname = Path(filename)
    if fname.exists() and not ignore_file:
        obj = jl.load(filename)
    else:
        obj = func(**kwargs)
        jl.dump(obj,fname,compress = True)        
    return obj
```

Changed Call:

```
file = Path("rf.pickle")
rf_clf = saveobj(file, rnd_cv.fit, ignore_file=False, X=X_train, y= np.ravel(y_train))
```

Although, I would still love to know, which one is better.

Comment: I think mine is better. Yours have to pass any additional parameters according to``func``. For mine, the call to ``saveobj `` doesn't change even if ``func`` changes.

Comment: @youkaichao Thanks for your inputs, though I was looking for a more subtle answer. More specifically, how globals and locals will be propagated and what kind of memory and computational complexity they add compared to a simple **kwargs call. BTW, I have accepted your answer as well

Comment: Nope, my answer is unaccepted :( You can only accept one answer.

Comment: All global variables and local variables are maintained by the python interpreter no matter you call ``globals()`` or not, so ``globals()`` and ``locals()`` requires negligible cost (just passing a reference).